# PHPAdmin on Redhat 6.4

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, redhat

I'm try into install the latest PhpMyAdmin into the Redhat 6.4 and I can't get it working and getting dependencies error, I'm try install through YUM REMI and other file repo, all I can get it working is the old version 2.11 which is very old.

I manually downloaded the Phpadmin 4.xx. RPM and using Yum localinstall and still not working.

The box is running PHP 5.6.9 and MySQL Server 5.6.22-log

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Please paste the dependency error messages

Answer (score 0):

Usually it gets to work if we do the following as preliminary steps

1. Firstly clean your metadata: This cleans up any xml metadata that may have been cached from any enabled repository

   `$ sudo yum clean metadata`
2. Then upgrade all of your system software to the latest version

   `$ sudo yum update`

---

But, if you have installed PHP 5.6.9 from remi repository, then need to check the **phpmyadmin version compatibility with php** from remi repository. Do not downgrade php if there is a mismatch. In that case try this

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install phpmyadmin
```

---

**If you get package not found**

The EPEL repo contains the phpMyAdmin package we are looking for.

```
sudo yum install epel-release
```

Once EPEL is done try

```
sudo yum install phpmyadmin
```

For reference:

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/install-phpmyadmin-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

http://www.krizna.com/centos/how-install-phpmyadmin-centos-6/

Comment: I clean the metedata and try the command but I get the package not found No package phpadmin available.
Error: Nothing to do
:

Comment: If phpMyAdmin is not available. try above steps

Comment: Hi, i did the command above, it just told me Package phpmyadmin-2.11.11.3-2.el6.rf.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: Anyone succuessful using phpadmin 4.x on php 5.6.9?  I check their site and it seems only compatible up to php 5.4

Comment: Seems that it is already installed. So have you tried configuring phpmyadmin

Comment: yes, it is installed with version 2.11, that is from all those repo. I want to install 4.0.1 , I try uninstall the 2.11 and install the 4.0, but not working, due to some php module is not available to for 5.6.9 yet.which phpmyadmin 4.0 needed those install first.

Comment: any more answers? anyone can manange to install the phpmyadmin into redhat 6.4? with php 5.4.x and mysql 5.5.x??? without getting dependenicies error?